# Why did the SE image uploader change the colors in this image?

Tags: bug, images, uploader

Take a look at [this image](https://web.archive.org/web/20190107105641if_/https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/739459main_acd97-0036-2.jpg) on nasa.gov.  The text in the image is yellow, the flight paths are white, and Neptune's orbit is green.

When I try to use the SE image uploader to include the image in a question, the colors change, as you can see here:

[image]

The text has turned green, the flight paths are blue, and Neptune's orbit is light blue.  Every color changed, actually.

When I uploaded the image directly to imgur.com, the colors [did not change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8XQD.jpg).

Why is the SE image uploader changing the colors of this image?

Note: This happens for me with Firefox 39 on both Windows XP and Mac OS X 10.7.5.  It also happens in Safari 6.0.2 on OS X.

Comment: Are you uploading from your computer or linking from the web?

Comment: Linking from the web.

Comment: So, looks like Chrome works just fine for someone... what browser are you using?

Comment: @pacoverflow could you please provide the Browser name and OS. I have no issue at all. See my answer below

Comment: Heh. Happened to my cup of coffee. I didn't have it afterwards. (Well, its just an image of purple coffee)

Answer (score 8):

It seems to do this even if uploaded from your computer:
(FF 39 for OSX)

[image: uploaded image]

Linked from URL:

[image: From URL]

BUT, if you direct link using the alt code rather than uploading to the servers, it's fine:

[image: Direct link]

`![Direct link](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/739459main_acd97-0036-2.jpg)`

Answer (score 3):

It's my **fault**... I accept it openly... /me runs away in shame... Sorry about this mess up.

Here is what happened. I hit save instead of cancel in the Pixlr tool which I used for checking res and it got uploaded in Chrome and FF (hires). But later when using Safari I downloaded fresh image, removed all the old ones from my download folder & uploaded it and you can see it's has problem.

Catija & Damkerng T. answers are correct.

---

Works for me in Google Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. I just downloaded the image from the direct link and re-uploaded it.

**Tech-specs**: (just in case needed)

Google Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)

Firefox 39.0

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late2013) - OS X Yosemite version 10.10.2

Here is the image:

[image]

Here is how Safari Browser **Upload** looks:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it's more of a browser issue? What browser did you use for this?

Comment: @Catija I added Tech-specs to my answer

Comment: @Catija Problem with Safari... it looks very weird see answer

Comment: my answer is FF, same version as yours.

Comment: @catija Wait.... something is totally wrong here I have problem in Safari Browser .... ie when viewing this post in Safari but when look FF or Chrome they look same to me what do u see

Comment: @catija to explain my earlier comment better I added screenshot from Safari browser view to my answer

Comment: @Catija I take it back ... i think it was cache issue. I cleared the cache and history .... looks ok BUT 2nd upload is Safari does have problem

Comment: @Catija also notice that in my Safari.... the background is Brown color... do u have Safari? Can you check

Comment: Yeah, the entire image looks red shifted in Safari. The only one that looks "right" is the one you uploaded from Chrome. Even the direct linked one in my answer (third one) looks a bit grey compared to the Chrome one.

Comment: @Catija thanks for confirming it... I'm totally lost here... what do u mean by direct link. How does this link looks in your Chrome: http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/739459main_acd97-0036-2.jpg

Comment: See the code snippet I posted at the very end of my answer? That's the code you use to directly link to the image on a site rather than uploading it to the SE image host. It's generally not recommended as the URL can die if the site changes their image policy or if the site dies entirely, so it's better to upload using the image upload.  When I view the image in Safari, it appears more "washed out" than in the other two browsers... meaning the black is more of a dark grey and all of the colors are more pale, not as vibrant.

Comment: @Catija i missed that. Thanks.

Comment: @Catija My Safari (in both OS X and Windows XP) suffers from the same "washed out" effect you described, except for the first image in HackerKarma's answer.

Comment: @Catija I can't upload any images via Chrome.... It crashed me while upload... and FF is doing the same too....

Comment: I found the issue... its my fault... please see my edit. Also, whoever gave Upvote today must be accidental as I just checked Pixlr tool save image on my PC against the original downloaded in Preview tool. They mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't have a conclusive answer, but this should give enough hints.

After a quick inspection of the two files (original: https://web.archive.org/web/20190107105641if_/https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/739459main_acd97-0036-2.jpg, SE's: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVZTk.jpg), I can see one obvious thing: the EXIF information was stripped out of the SE's version entirely. EXIF tags include several crucial things that may affect how the image will be rendered. Among these are things like WhitePoint, PrimaryChromaticities, ColorMap, WhiteBalance, and ColorSpace. And that is the cause of the problem, IMHO, though I'm not quite sure why and how the EXIF information removal happens when we upload an image.

Anyway, here is my simple workaround: save such an image as PNG first, then upload it. Here is my test result:

[image]

Comment: I found the issue... See my edit in the answer

Comment: EXIF data is removed by Imgur

Comment: Imgur strips out the EXIF data on purpose.  EXIF data may contain GPS data, and people might not want others to know where they are located.